# Regular Expression ^(\+\d+\s?)?\d+$

Tags: javascript

Could somebody tell me what the requirments are for the following regular expression?

```
^(\+\d+\s?)?\d+$
```

I'm trying to book a ticket at CheapTicket.nl but the phone number doesn't match the regular expression.

Comment: that first `+` makes it invalid

Comment: use this https://regex101.com

Comment: That is not a valid regular expression; it'll cause a syntax error in JavaScript.

Comment: @Deryck: It was just that the OP hadn't marked it up correctly, there was a \ in front of it to make it a literal.

Comment: in that case just typing a line of numbers will pass the test.

Comment: Well that website is pretty poor if you have to check the source code of the website to be able to input a phone number in... I'd check whether the site is legitimate or not before booking on that site.

Comment: Well, it's weird because when the field turns green (OK), and you submit you get an modal popup that the phone number is not correct.. Can't get it to work but I think that there are multiple functions that check the phone number and that they work against each other.

Comment: @Peacy: They must do, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

It requires that the string contain digits, optionally preceded by a plus sign with at least one digit and one optional whitespace character.

So `123456` would be valid (no leading `+nnn`), as would `+123 456789` or `+123456789`. You must not have any spaces at the beginning or end. Letters and punctuation (other than the leading `+`) aren't allowed anywhere.

[Visual example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tI8jO3/1)